# How do I apply a function to only a certain value in a list?

Tags: python-2.7

So I have to make a version update program that updates the values in the version number. So for 11.3.4.5, I want my index function to update a number in that list, and then change all remaining values to 0. So if I want the index to be 0, it would change the first value of the list, so the new list would be 12.0.0.0.If someone could just show me how to set it up, that would be great. This is what I have so far, but I'm so stuck:

```
def updateVersion(numbers, index): 
   version = []
   index = 
       for i in numbers:
          if any(version):
          i + 1
          return version
```

Answer (score 0):

say you provide a list as an arg:

```
def updateVersion(currVersion, index):
     if index == 0:
         return [currVersion[0] + 1] + [0] * (len(currVersion) - 1)
     else:
         return [currVersion[0], index] + [0] * (len(currVersion) - 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I got your question correct. But I would do something like this:

```
current_version = [11,3,4,5] 

def updateVersion(version, index):

    i = 0
    new_version = [None] * len(version)#get length of the Version - number and create an empty list with the same length

    for number in version:
        if i == index: # increment the Version Number
            new_version[i] = version[i] + 1
        elif i > index: # All numbers after the increment are 0
            new_version[i] = 0
        else:
            new_version[i] = version[i]
        i = i + 1 

    return new_version

print str(updateVersion(current_version, 0))#just for testing
```

So here the output would be:

```
[12,0,0,0]
```